# Change font color in a table depending on its string value in php

Tags: php

I have tried a few different options, but just cant get my head around this. 
I want the font in a table cell to change according to its string value:
For instance, if the value is "ES" then turn the font orange, Red for "X" and grey for "n/a"
***the code works perfectly, just want to add color***

(basicly, the query checks the employee's jobtitle to see if he requires a certificate and returns a "n/a" if he doesn't, if he does, checks the date the certificate was obtained (valid for 1 year) and see weather it has expired, will expire soon or if it is valid)

Following is a snippet of my php script:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT`employee`.`empl_idno`, IF( `jobtitle`.`jt_medical`='n/a',`jobtitle`.`jt_medical`, IF(  `certs`.`cert_medical` = 0, 'O',IF( (DATEDIFF((DATE_ADD(`certs`.`cert_medical`, INTERVAL 365 DAY)),CURDATE())) < 1, 'X', IF( (DATEDIFF((DATE_ADD(`certs`.`cert_medical`, INTERVAL 365 DAY)),CURDATE())) < 30, 'ES', 'ok')))) AS medical,IF( `jobtitle`.`jt_hse_ind`='n/a', `jobtitle`.`jt_hse_ind`, IF( `certs`.`cert_hse_ind` = 0, 'O IF( (DATEDIFF((DATE_ADD(`certs`.`cert_hse_ind`, INTERVAL 365 DAY)),CURDATE())) < 1, 'X', IF( (DATEDIFF((DATE_ADD(`certs`.`cert_hse_ind`, INTERVAL 365 DAY)),CURDATE())) < 30, 'ES', 'ok')))) AS hse_ind,IF( `jobtitle`.`jt_tf_ind`='n/a', `jobtitle`.`jt_tf_ind`, IF( `certs`.`cert_tf_ind` = 0, 'O',IF((DATEDIFF((DATE_ADD(`certs`.`cert_tf_ind`, INTERVAL 365 DAY)),CURDATE())) < 1, 'X', IF( (DATEDIFF((DATE_ADD(`certs`.`cert_tf_ind`, INTERVAL 365 DAY)),CURDATE())) < 30, 'ES', 'ok')))) AS tf_ind FROM `employee` JOIN `jobtitle` ON `employee`.`jobtitle_id` = `jobtitle`.`jobtitle_id` JOIN `certs` ON `certs`.`empl_idno` = `employee`.`empl_idno` WHERE `employee`.`empl_jc_code` = '$empl_jc_code'AND `employee`.`jobtitle_id` = '$jobtitle_id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
echo "<table><br>
    <thead><tr>
     <th>ID No</th>
    <th class='vertical'>Medical Surveillance</th>
     <th class='vertical'>HSE Induction</th>
     <th class='vertical'>Topfix Induction</th>
    </tr></thead>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($row);
    echo "<tr>\n
            <td>$empl_idno</td>\n
            <td>$medical </td>\n 
            <td>$hse_ind</td>\n
            <td>$tf_ind</td>\n
            </tr>\n";
}
echo "</table><br>";
?>
```

Comment: A good side advice: Don't use echo to print a full html output. That increases the chance for mistakes rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {
        extract($row);  
        echo "<tr>\n
```

to

```
 $colors = ['ES' => 'orange', 'X' => 'red', 'n/a' => 'gray'];

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {
        extract($row);  
        echo "<tr".(isset($colors[$tf_ind]) ? " style=\"color:".$colors[$tf_ind]."\"" : "") .">\n
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but the script gave me an "error on Page", changed the script to: $colors = "['ES' => 'orange', 'X' => 'red', 'n/a' => 'gray']";
 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
 {
  extract($row);  
  echo "<tr>\n
   <td>$empl_idno</td>\n
   <td>$medical</td>\n 
   <td>$hse_ind</td>\n
   <td '.(isset($colors[tf_ind]) ? ' style=\'color:'.$colors[tf_ind].'\'' : '') .'>$tf_ind</td>\n

Comment: @JJMorgan You added double quotes in the first line with `$colors`.

Comment: Also to highlight only the last cell, change that line to `<td '.(isset($colors[$tf_ind]) ? ' style="color:'.$colors[$tf_ind].'"' : '') .'>'.$tf_ind.'</td>\n`

Comment: I have tried this, but I only get a blank screen. Thus I cannot seem to get my head around this. Is there maybe another way?

Comment: Try it again with copy paste, don't change anything.

Comment: Still not working, thank you for the help. I'll have to look at some other way to do this. Once again, thank you for the help